# Customize Jetstream Login Page Validation Error Messages in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

How can I Customize Jetstream Login Page Validation Error Messages in Laravel 9??
When i input wrong email & password it shows "credentials does not match" but i want to customize this message..
How can i do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open this file `project/resources/lang/en/auth.php` you can update the message from there

`'failed' => 'Whoops! These credentials do not match our records.',`